# What can I put in my question true/false question maker so that it can be user friendly?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, methods, while-loop, object-oriented-database

I am not quite done with my code yet, but I need help with my true/false question maker so that it can set user inputted questions as either true or false. Then when the program is executed with def take_quiz(self): method, the user will have to put in 't' or 'f' as true or false respectively.

I plan to have to have a database named questlist to store the questions and an answerbase to store 't' or 'f' respectively to the question base.

This is the code I got down so far, and I would appreciate any help with adding on to it.

```
class Quiz:
    
    #start of quiz
    def __init__(self):
        #self.short_quiz
        print("Welcome to 5 true or false questions quiz maker.")
        questlist = []
       
    
    #asks the user to input 5 questions with either true or false.
    def set_question(self):
        count = 1
        print("Please input 5 true or false questions, type 't' for true and 'f' for false.")
        while count <= 5:
            quest = str(input("Please enter question " + str(count )+ ": " ))
            
            trufal = str(input("Is question " + str(count) + " true or false? "))
                while trufal is not ("t") or ("f"):
                    #repeats if user did not input either 't' or 'f'
                                
            count += 1
      
    #When executed, the program will ask the true/false questions the user inputed in set_questions
   # def take_quiz(self):
    
    
    #gives back the user their score once completed
    
    #percentage = ((score/5)* 100)
    #score = str(score)
    #percentage = str(percentage)
    #print ("Your score is " + score + " out of 5 and " + percentage + "%". )

        
user = Quiz()
user.set_question()
```

Comment: `str(input(...))` is redundant/unnecessary. Python 3's `input` returns a `str`, calling `str` on it is just wasteful thumb twiddling. Drop the `str()` wrapping.

Comment: `while trufal is not ("t") or ("f"):` is wrong on multiple levels: 1) Use `==`/`!=` for value comparison, don't use identity comparisons (`is`/`is not`) for anything but `None` until you actually understand what they do. 2) What you wrote is unconditionally true; the `or` is true if either side is true, and `"f"` is always true, so it's an infinite loop. You wanted `while trufal not in ("t", "f"):` (verifying it is not contained in the collection of `"t"` and `"f"`).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm just not a good programmer but I am willing to improve.